# Are add-ons like Redis To Go secure for Heroku/EC2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, heroku, amazon-ec2, redis

I'm looking into using Heroku as our platform instead of managing our own systems. We have a Ruby/Rails stack and use Resque as our background job processor. I'm evaluating addons such as RedisToGo and RedisGreen, but it looks like there's no secure transport layer for all the services. However, according to [RedisGreen's FAQ](http://www.redisgreen.net/faq.html) it doesn't matter:

> **Do you offer an encrypted connection to your servers?**
>
> No. Most organizations working in EC2 or Heroku treat Amazon’s internal network as a “trusted” one, so transport-level security doesn’t make much sense. We recommend against transferring data that should be secure over the open Internet.

As an Ops guy, makes me feel a bit queasy to have unencrypted data transfers. On the other hand, they make a good point. If Amazon is considered a trust internal network, then we wouldn't have to worry about 3rd parties trying to sniff us out.

So my question: is it safe to use these add-ons if I'm on the Heroku/EC2 ecosystem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used AWS for years without any problems and most AWS users don't seem to be malicious. Also, Amazon has a comprehensive monitoring solution for their infrastructure.  For example, they would be able to tell if another customer is trying to hack into your server in a few minutes if not seconds. I believe AWS also doesn't allow promiscuous mode on their Virtual/Physical networking infrastructure.

However, you have to also see how secure you want to be about your data. If you want 100% security that no other user is going to sniff your data then encrypt your connections/data transfers. Although unlikely, other AWS users could potentially sniff the data if they are sharing the same ethernet segment.

Comment: You're definitely right that AWS doesn't allow promiscuous mode: http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1697. But won't this prevent other users sniffing on the same ethernet segment as well? (Thanks for the reply Rico)

Comment: That's right disabling promiscuous mode should prevent ethernet sniffing but like anything, nothing is 100% guaranteed, hackers can be creative if you know what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

The current recommendation is to use a secure proxy with Redis if you want to have SSL encryption of your traffic (see the debate at https://code.google.com/p/redis/issues/detail?id=71 for example). AFAIK, only Redis Cloud can offer that functionality among existing Heroku's Redis providers.

As for whether security is a requirement for Heroku apps and their add-on over AWS, that really has to do with your data's nature and the risk of it being read by a potentially malicious party. Just remember that even a very low risk is still a risk and no security mechanism is unbreakable, so it's basically a matter of how much you're willing to invest to make it harder for someone to mess with you stuff.

(Due diligence - I work at Garantia Data, the company operating Redis Cloud and Memcached Cloud.)

Answer (score 0):

I consider this highly dangerous. Heroku, for example, suggests running apps locally for development and copying the config to do so:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local

What that implies is that your laptop will then do an unencrypted connection - potentially through public wifis and definitely through the public internet - to your Redis To Go instance. As such, whether AWS will allow sniffing on their network or not is then completely irrelevant.